# How do I play VR games in Bigscreen (Beta)?

Tags: vive, bigscreen

In Bigscreen (Beta), how can I play Vive games while in a lobby? I heard with the Oculus Rift, you can open up Oculus Home and play a VR game through the remote desktop in a lobby.

Is there an equivalent to do that with the HTC Vive while playing Bigscreen?